# Overlay Table on top of Graph - Matplotlib/Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been trying to produce a line graph using with a table overlaid on the top that depicts some metrics. The line graph has two lines (one random values 0-1, and an upward trend line). Both of the data are in pandas dataframes. I have to use matplotlib due to the requirements I'm working under.

When I attempt to overlay the table, the lines beneath the table are visible through each cell. As seen here:

[Table Cells Transparent (example only)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4zzm.png)

I would ideally like to have the table on top of the graph with some shadows and colors to the cells and no transparency of the lines beneath. As seen here:

[Table Cell Not Transparent (example only)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wkm9.png)

I am able to do the cell colors, but they are still somewhat transparent and I still get the graph lines seen through them.

Here's the relevant code:

```
def plot_data(data, title, x_label, y_label, stats):
    
    #data = DataFrame with relevant data for the line charts
    #title = string for chart title
    #x_label = string for the x_label
    #x_label = string for the x_label
    #stats = DataFrame with relevant statistics


    styles = ['g-', 'r-']
    figure = plt.figure()
    figure = data.plot(title=title, style=styles)
    figure.grid()
    figure.set_xlabel(x_label)
    figure.set_ylabel(y_label)
    table = plt.table(cellText=stats.round(4).values, rowLabels=stats.index,
                      colLabels=stats.columns, colWidths=[0.17]*3,
                      loc="center right")
    table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    table.set_fontsize(7)
    
    return figure
```

I have tried using subplot, add_axes, coloring cells. I cannot figure out how to get this to work. Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Please edit you question so that you code can be directly copy-pasted to obtain the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increase the [zorder](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html) of your table so that it is on top of the lines:

```
table = plt.table(cellText=stats.round(4).values, rowLabels=stats.index,
                  colLabels=stats.columns, colWidths=[0.17]*3,
                  loc="center right",
                  zorder=10, # <--- highest value is on top
                 )
```